# Why must I wait to reward an existing answer when giving out a bounty?

Tags: discussion

A few years ago JMac posted an answer that helped me a lot in ([this](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/12187/how-do-i-resign-when-i-know-my-employer-will-lose-a-big-client-when-i-leave)) post. Now  that I'm active around here and have something to give back I thought I would pass him some reputation to him via a bounty.

When I've started the bounty I selected "Reward Existing Answer" however I can't award it until I wait for 24 hours. Since the answer is already there and the post is a few years old, is this really necessary?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This has been discussed on various metas before.

- [Waiting 24 hours to reward an existing answer is completely illogical](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/268362/waiting-24-hours-to-reward-an-existing-answer-is-completely-illogical) (Global Meta): No consensus
- [Answer on Sci-Fi explaining some of the reasons behind it](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5248/42419)
- [Answer on Math describing the potential for abuse by high-rep users](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10105)
- [Cross-Validated answer describing that it's to promote visibility of both the question and answers](https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2633)

Summary of potential reasons:

- **promote the visibility** of the question and its answers by making it a featured question
- **limit the ability to transfer reputation** between users
- **respect the transparency of the bounty system**: anyone should be able to earn it by writing a great answer, potentially writing an even better answer than the one you initially wanted to reward